# $\gcd(a,b,c)\!=\!1\Rightarrow \gcd(az+b,c)\!=\! 1$ for some $z$ [Coprime Dirichlet Theorem]

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

I can't crack this one.

> Prove: If $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$ then there exists $z$ such that $\gcd(az+b,c) = 1$ (the only constraint is that  $a,b,c,z \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $c\neq 0)$

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This can be solved *intuitively* by using a slight twist on Euclid's idea for generating new primes. Euclid employed $\,1 + p_1\cdots p_n$ is coprime to $\,c = p_1\cdots p_n.\,$ Stieltjes noted the generalization that, further,  $\ \color{#c00}{p_1\cdots p_k} +\, \color{#0a0}{p_{k+1}\cdots p_n}\,$ is coprime to $\,c\,$ too, which motivates the following

**Key Idea**  coprimes to $\,c\neq 0\,$ arise by partitioning  into $\rm\color{#c00}{two}\ \color{#0a0}{summands}$ all prime factors of $\,c,\,$ i.e.

**Theorem** $\ \ \color{#c00}a+\color{#0a0}b\ $ is coprime to $\ c\neq 0\:$ if every prime factor of $\,c\,$ divides $\,a\,$ or $\,b,\,$ but not both.

**Proof** $\ $ If not then  $\,a+b\,$ and $\,c\,$ have a common prime factor $\,p.\,$ By hypothesis $\,p\mid a\,$ or $\,p\mid b.\,$ Wlog, say $\,p\mid b.\,$ Then $\,p\mid (a+b)-b = a,\,$ so $\,p\,$ divides both $\,a,b,\,$ contra hypothesis. $\,\ \bf\small QED$

The OP seeks $\,\color{#c00}{az}+\color{#0a0}b\,$ coprime to $\,c,\,$  so it suffices to choose $\,z\,$ such that each prime factor $\,p\,$ of $\,c\,$ divides exactly one of $\,az\,$ or $\,b.\,$ Note $\,p\,$ can't divide both $\,a,b,\,$ else $\,p\mid a,b,c,\,$ contra hypothesis. Thus it suffices to let $\,z\,$  be the product of primes in $\,c\,$ that do not occur in $\,b\,$ (or in $\,a).\,$ $\ \bf\small QED$

**Remark** $ $ Note how the solution becomes quite obvious after employing Stieltjes idea, amounting to nothing but a trivial calculation of a difference of sets (of primes)

Note: expensive prime factorization is not required, we can efficiently compute solutions using iterated gcds, e.g. see the $\rm gdc$ function [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3085179/242)

Comment: Letting $z$ be the product of primes in $c$ that do not occur in $b$ suffices. Or just simply let $z$ be $c$ excluding all common primes with $b$. This provides a polynomial-time algorithm: $z = c / \gcd(c, b^{\log_2 c})$.

Comment: @PinkRabbit Yes, of course, that is already mentioned - follow the link.

Answer (score 9):

Assume therefore that  $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$ with $c\ne0$.
Let $p$ be a prime dividing $c$.
Then $0\cdot a+b=b$ and $1\cdot a+b=a+b$ cannot both be multiples of $p$ as that would mean $p\mid \gcd(a,b,c)$. Thus for each $p\mid c$ there exists $z_p$ with $p\not\mid az_p+b$.
By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, there exists $z$ with $z\equiv z_p\pmod p$ for all (finitely many) $p\mid c$. Since $az+b\equiv az_p+b\pmod p$ we conclude that $p\not \mid az+b$. Consequently, $\gcd(a+zb,c)=1$.

Note that the hypothesis $c\neq 0$ is necessary. Consider $a=5$, $b=7$, $c=0$.
Then $\gcd(a,b,c)=\gcd(7,5)=1$ whereas $\gcd(az+b,c)=|az+b|\ne 1$, no matter what $z$ we choose.

Answer (score 6):

Let $p_1,\ldots,p_k$ be the primes that divide $c$ (assuming $c \ne 0$) and also divide $az+b$ for some $z$. Note that no $p_i$ can divide $a$, since then it would divide $b$ as well.

It follows that two distinct values of $z$ for which some fixed $p_i$ divides $az+b$ must differ by a multiple of $p$. Hence there is a unique $z_i$ with $0 < z_i < p_i$ with $p_i|(az_i+b)$ and $p_i|(az+b) \Leftrightarrow z \equiv z_i \bmod p_i$.

Now choose numbers $y_i$ with $0 \le y_i < p_i$ and $y_i \ne z_i$. By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, there is a $z$ with $z \equiv y_i \bmod p_i$ for each $i$ and hence $az+b$ is not divisible by $p_i$ and so ${\rm gcd}(az+b,c)=1$.

Answer (score 3):

This question is closely related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609810/show-that-if-a-b-and-c-are-integers-such-that-a-b-1-then-there-i/610706#610706) one. There is a small difference, but apparently both solutions provided there fit in here too, after a very small modification:

Assume $c\neq0$.

Let $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_i$ be the common prime divisors of $c$ and $b$, with their respective powers $e_1,\ldots,e_i$ in the prime factorisation of $c$.

If we set $d=p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_i^{e_i}$, then $z=\frac cd$ will satisfy $\gcd(az+b,c)=1$.

To see why, suppose $q$ is prime and $q$ divides both $c$ and $az+b$.
If $q\mid b$, then we should have $q\mid az$ which is impossible since $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$ and $\gcd(z,b)=1$. If $q\nmid b$, then $q\mid z$ by the definition of $z$, and therefore $q\nmid az+b$, a contradiction again.

---

An alternative with induction:

Clearly the desired theorem is true for $a,c=\pm 1$.

Now suppose we know it's true for all $a,c$ satisfying $|a|+|c|\leq s$. (We will do induction on $s$.)

Let $|a|>1$. (The case $a=\pm1$ is trivial and needs no induction, in fact.)

If $a\mid c$, let $c=c'a$ and then $(za+b,c)=(za+b,c'a)=(za+b,c')$ for all $z$, because we are given $(a,b,c)=1$. Now $|a|+|c'|<|a|+|c|$ and we conclude, by the induction hypothesis, there is a $z$ satisfying $(za+b,c)=1$.

If $a\nmid c$, let $g=(a,c)$.

We are looking for an integer $d$ with $(d,c)=1$ such that $az+kc=d-b$ has a solution for $z$ and $k$. (This is simply rewriting $(az+b,c)=1$ where $d\equiv az+b\pmod c$.)

It is well know that such a linear equation has a solution if and only if $g\mid d-b$, or equivalently $d=z'g+b$ for some $z'$. Because $|g|<|a|$ we can again use the induction hypothesis, and conclude that there exists such a $z'$, and therefore there exists such $z$.

Comment: This method is essentially a slight twist on Euclid's method for generating primes - see my answer for that viewpoint.

Comment: Indeed, that was in some sense how I reasoned too, when devising my answer on that other question.

Answer (score 1):

We have a (unique) decomposition $c = c' \cdot c''$, where $(c',a)=1$, and the prime divisors of $c''$ divide $a$.

Now, with Chinese remainder, produce $b_1$ such that

$$ b_1 \equiv b \mod a \\
   b_1 \equiv 1 \mod c'$$

We have $b_1 = b + z a$, and $(b_1, c)= 1$. Indeed, $(b_1, c') = 1$, and also $(b, c'' ) = 1$, since $(b,a,c) = 1$.

Note: the proof also works in a Dedekind domain, where instead of $(c)$ we can consider a non-zero ideal $\mathcal{C}$.