# Proof verification: Proving that $\gcd(p,q,r)>1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

If gcd(p,q,r) = 1
Prove that there is an integer A such that
gcd(p, q+Ar) = 1

Is the following proof good (correct)?

If we assume for the sake of contradiction that $\gcd(p,q+Ar)$ $>1\ \forall A\in \mathbb{Z}...(\text{I})$, then also (by symmetry) $\gcd(q,r+Ap)$ $>1\ \forall A\in \mathbb{Z}...(\text{II})$ and $\gcd(r,p+Cq)$ $>1\ \forall A\in \mathbb{Z}...(\text{III})$. Now since $\gcd(p,q,r)$ $=\gcd(\gcd(p,q),r)$, it will suffice to show that $\gcd(\gcd(p,q),r)$ $>1$. For the sake of brevity let $g$ $=\gcd(p,q)$, hence $p$ $=gp'$ and $q$ $=gq'$ for some relatively prime integers $p',q'$. We will assume to the contrary that $\gcd(g,r)$ $=1$, from which (Bezout) there will exist $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $gx+ry$ $=1$, or $ry$ $=1-gx...(\alpha)$. Thus, the inequality $(\text{I})$ becomes $\gcd(gp',gq'+Ar)$ $>1\ \forall A\in \mathbb{Z}$. Setting $A$ $=A'y$ for some arbitrary integer $A'$, we get $\gcd(gp',gq'+A'ry)$ $>1\ \forall A'\in \mathbb{Z}$, or equivalently (by $(\alpha)$) $\gcd(gp',gq'+A'-A'gx)$ $>1\ \forall A'\in \mathbb{Z}$. So setting $A'$ $=p'$ yields (Euclidean Algorithm) $\gcd(gp',gq'+p')$ $>1\ \forall A'\in \mathbb{Z}$. Now, if $\gcd(g,p')$ $=1$ then the proof is complete, so it will suffice to prove this. Notice that the inequality $(\text{II})$ is equivalent to $\gcd(gq',r+q')$ $>1$. (The proof is identical to what has been done previously and the details are omitted.) There are two cases to distinguish. If $\gcd(g,q')$ $=1$, then by symmetry it will also be possible for $\gcd(g,p')$ $=1$ to hold (in some other circumstances), and the proof is complete. Otherwise, if $\gcd(g,q')$ $>1$ then it forces $\gcd(g,p')$ $=1$ to hold, and the proof is complete. Thus, in both cases the proof is complete. Q.E.D.

I am mainly unsure about the symmetry statements. The first one is explicitly mentioned in brackets ("by symmetry"); the second one arises later on in the proof. So it will be helpful to read the proof if you can, I will really appreciate it.

Comment: Your very first sentence gives an assertion that isn't immediately obvious; why is it true?

Comment: @GregMartin: By symmetry

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647600 Though this question is different as it asks for a proof verification.

Comment: @GregMartin: I inserted the real problem

Comment: Taking $A=0$, $gcd(p,q) > 1$. Then certainly $gcd(p, q, r)> 1$.

Comment: To whoever did the -1 vote, care to explain why?

Comment: @user45220: That's just rude. You changed the problem statement; what I wrote relates to the formulation I saw a few minutes ago which didn't seem to make sense.

Comment: @barto: See comment above.

Comment: @gnometorule: Sorry my friend, email me at omglogo@hotmail.co.uk if you need help with something, I will try to repay you for my rudeness.

Comment: @gnometorule no, it's the contrapositive of the original statement.

Comment: @user45220: My comment relates to a comment you deleted too ("rubbish"). And that's the last bit of time I waste on this.

Comment: @user45220 Perhaps somebody downvoted because as it is now formulated your question expects users to read your entire proof; it would be helpful to point out which steps you feel unsure about. And better don't publish you e-mail like this.

Comment: @barto: It's not, or at least not without further intermediate steps.

Comment: @barto: I am mainly unsure about the symmetry statements. The first one is explicitly mentioned in brackets ("by symmetry"); the second one arises later on in the proof. So it will be helpful to read the proof if you can, I will really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It does not follow by symmetry from $\gcd(p,q+Ar)>1$ for all $A$ that $\gcd(q,r+Ap)>1$ and $\gcd(r,p+Cq)>1$ for all $A,C$. When you use a symmetry argument, it means that the 'symmetric' statement can be *proven* in an analoguous way.
What you are doing here is *making an assumption* and then 'by symmetry', *assuming* another statement. So basically you are assuming too much for what the negation of "$\gcd(p,q,r)=1$" is worth.

Comment: I didn't quite understand the explanation. Can you explain some more? (The whole thing)