# Even number sum proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that every even number $k\geqslant 8$ can be represented as $m,n\in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{1\}$
$$k=m+n$$
and $\gcd(m,n)=1$.

I was able to do it, if $k$ is an odd number but not if it is even. I could use some hints.

Comment: Hint: if $m$ and $n$ are close to each other, they can't have many factors in common...

Comment: Another hint:  Try some examples first. How can you write 12 as a sum of two relatively prime numbers?  What about 10?

Comment: Further hint: $\,m,n\,$ have equal parity so, being coprime, both are odd. So consider close odds.

Answer (score 1):

If $k = 4m: m \in \Bbb{N}$ then $k = (2m-1) + (2m+1)$ and both of those terms are odd and differ by exactly $2$, so one step of Euclid's algorithm shows that $$\gcd(2m+1,2,-1) = \gcd(2m-1,2) = 1.$$

Having taken care of all multiples of $4$, now consider $k = 4m+2$. In that case, $k = (2m-3) + (2m+1)$ and 
$$\gcd(2m+1,2,2m-3) = \gcd(2m-3,4) = 1$$ since $2m-3$ contains no powers of $2$.

Comment: I changed the four instance of \text{gcd} to \gcd in this answer.  The latter provides proper spacing between $\gcd$ and whatever precedes it.  Contrast $a\text{gcd}(b,c)$ with $a\gcd(b,c)$.  They look different. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $\mathrm{gcd}(k, m) = 1$, then if $q$ is an integer such that $q \mid m$ and $q \mid k-m$, then $$q \mid (k-m) + m = k$$

Can you deduce that $m$ and $k-m$ are coprime?

Comment: This is the germ of the idea behind Stieltjes generalization of Euclid's proof that there are infinitely many primes, and it often [proves useful.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/647665/242)

Answer (score 0):

Assume $k\geq 8$. By Bertrand's postulate (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BertrandsPostulate.html), there exists a prime number $p$ between $\frac{k}{2}$ and $k-2$. Now $p$ and $k-p$ clearly are coprime.

Comment: Surely this is overkill.