# Is/when is this property about the totative subset of $(\mathbb{Z}_n , +_n)$ true?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Is it possible to show (or when is it true); that for the **group** $\mathbb{Z}^+_n :=(\mathbb{Z}_n , +_n) $, there exists an $a \in \mathbb{Z}^+_n$ for each $z \in \mathbb{Z}^+_n$, where both $z+_n a$ and $z+_n -a$ are totatives of $n$?

**Additional**
What is the smallest $a$ that can be constructed?

Comment: What does it mean to be totative?

Comment: A **totative** of some number $n :=$ a number that is coprime to $n$.

Comment: I guess it is true. If $hcf(z,n)=z$ then we can pick an $a$ which is a product of all prime divisors of $n$ except those prime numbers which are factors of $z$. In that case both $z+a$ and $z-a$ wont be divisible by any   factor of $z$.

Comment: Actually, you do not seem to even be using that $z$ divides $n$ there. Just pick $a$ as the product of those primes which divide $n$ but $z$.

Comment: Considering $n=210$ and $z=8$. And naturally choosing $a=105$. It's true that $113$ (repeated) is a totative of $210$. But it is the case that if we choose $a=21$, both $29$ and $197$ are also totatives of $210$. So I guess my question is, why is that?

Comment: You mean why we can pick more than one $a$ that works? That is just because there is a pretty decent number of totatives (relatively).

Comment: My aim is to show that there is a small enough $a$. Taking $n$ to be a **primorial** number $ P_x\# := p_1 \times p_2 \times ... \times p_x$ ($p$ are primes), I am wondering if there exists an $a< \frac{1}{2} p_x^2$.

Comment: Do you want to say "for each $z \in \mathbb{Z}^+_n$ there exists an $a \in \mathbb{Z}^+_n$..."?

Comment: @user26857 Exactly, the passive expression is equivalent in meaning, only the focus differs. From my interest, the focus on the existence of $a$ occurred naturally due to my comment before.

Comment: Hint: see [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/647665/242)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show that

> for each $z\in\mathbb{Z}_n$ there exists $a\in\mathbb{Z}_n$ such that $\gcd(z\pm a,n)=1$,

then proceed like this:
If $\gcd(z,n)=1$ then set $a=0$.
Otherwise $\gcd(z,n)>1$. If for any prime $p$ such that $p\mid n$ we have $p\mid z$ then set $a=1$. Otherwise, there is $p\mid n$ such that $p\nmid z$. In this case let $a$ be the product of all primes in $n$ which don't appear in $z$.

Comment: Thank you. So for additional points, is it possible to construct a suitable $a$, which is **smaller than** the product of all primes in $n$ which don't appear in $z$? (Consider $n=210$, $z=8$. Your method sets $a=105$, which obeys the criteria. But so does $a=21$).

Comment: Careful, $5$ is not a totative of $210$

Comment: Actually, I can explain the case mentioned above, by considering a $8$ modulo $2,3,5$ and $7$; $21$ modulo $2,3,5$ and $7$, and recognizing that totatives of $210$ are not equivalent to $0$ modulo $2,3,5$ or $7$. So by sort of cross analysis of modulos we can find all $a$ for a $z$ I think...

Comment: Maybe finding a minimal $a$ is not an easy task. See [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/224013/minimal-solution-of-simultaneous-congruences).

Comment: You could also think on this problem by using [CRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Theorem_statement). Write $n=p_1^{k_1}\cdots p_r^{k_r}$. Then $z$ corresponds to some $(z_1,\dots,z_r)$ and $a$ to an $(a_1,\dots,a_r)$, where $z_i,a_i\in\mathbb Z_{p_i^{k_i}}$. You need $z_i-a_i$ invertible in $\mathbb Z_{p_i^{k_i}}$. This way is very easy to find a suitable $a_i$, but the minimality is a different story. It seems to be difficult even for $n$ square-free.

Comment: Thanks alot for the link. If we can show that for $n$ being a **primorial number** $P_x\# := p_1 \times p_2 \times ... \times p_x$ (where $p$ are consecutive primes), that for all $z$ there exists an $a <\frac{1}{2}p^2_x$, then we have proved **Goldbach's conjecture**. So I would be disappointed if it wasn't difficult!