# If $\gcd(u,m)=1$ then there exists an integer $k_1\in\Bbb Z$ such that $\gcd(mk_1+u,mk)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I believe that the following statement is true, but I couldn't prove it.

Let $u,m,k\in \Bbb Z$. If $\gcd(u,m)=1$ then there exists an integer $k_1\in\Bbb Z$ such that $\gcd(mk_1+u,mk)=1$
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you believe this?

Comment: We have a natural surjective ring homomorphism $\Bbb Z/mk\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$ given by $a+mk\Bbb Z\mapsto a+m\Bbb Z$. And we know that the restriction map of $(\Bbb Z/mk\Bbb Z)^{\times}$ into $(\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z)^{\times}$ is also surjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assertion holds for $k\neq 0$, for by [Dirichlet's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletsTheorem.html) the arithmetic progression $u+hm$ for $h\in\Bbb Z$ contains infinitely many prime numbers hence at least one of them doesn't divide (and, thus, it is prime with) $mk$.

Alternatively, take $k_1$ to be the product of prime divisors of $k $ which doesn't divide  $u $.

See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/647600).