# Why does the pair $(c,d)\in\mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z$ always has a coprime lift?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If we know $c,d\in\mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z$ and $\gcd(c,d,N)=1$. How do we prove there always exist $k_1, k_2\in\mathbb Z$ such that $\gcd(c+k_1N, d+k_2N)=1$ ?

It looks simple but I've been stuck for long. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Bezout's identity is an "if and only if"

Comment: @Mummytheturkey  Hi. I tried to use Bezout's identity, that is, to prove $\gcd(+_1,+_2)=1$, I try to prove there is a $\mathbb Z$ linear combination of these two numbers that equals to $1$. Use the assumption, I know there is always a linear combination of $c,d,N$ that equals to $1$. But then I am stuck as I cannot always split the term with $N$ to add them as part of $c$ and $d$. Can you elaborate a little bit more on that? Thank you

Comment: anything unclear

Comment: By a [simple proof:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/647665/242) $(c,N,d)=1\Rightarrow \exists k\!: (\overbrace{c\!+\!k N}^{\large C},d)=1.\,$ Applied again $\exists j\!: (C,d\!+\!jN)=1\,$ by $(C,d,N) = (c\!+\!k N,d,N)=(c,d,N)=1.\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$s = \prod_{p\ |\ c,p\ \nmid\ N} p$$

Take $u$ such that $$uN=1-d\bmod s$$

$d+uN=d\bmod \gcd(c,N)$ is a unit and $d+uN=1\bmod s$ is a unit thus
$$\gcd(c,d+uN)=1$$

Comment: Thank you! This is an elegant proof.