# If $\gcd(a,b)=d_1$ and $\gcd(b,c)=d_2$, what can we say about $\gcd(a,c)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

If $\gcd(a,b)=d_1$ and $\gcd(b,c)=d_2$. Here $d_1$ and $d_2$ are not $1$.  In addition we have $\gcd(d_1,d_2)=1$. Can we say $\gcd(a,c)=1$ ? The question seems easy but I am not able to see whether it is true or not? If it is true please help me to prove this! Thank you!

Comment: What if $d_1=d_2=1, a=c$?

Comment: Let $a=6, b=10, c=15$.

Comment: The hypotheses are equivalent to $(b,a)>1,\ (b,c)>1,\ (b,(a,c)) = 1,\,$ i.e. $b$ is not coprime to both $a$ & $c$ but $b$ is coprime to their gcd. Now it is easy to see how to construct counterexamples, e.g. if $A,B,C$ are the sets of prime factors of $a,b,c$ then we need $B$ to meet $A$ & $C$ but not $A\cap C$, so now it's a simple set-theory problem (boolean algebra).

Comment: Such *set-theoretic reductions* often greatly simplify number theory problems, e.g. see [Stieltjes *coprime* form](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/647665/242) of Dirichlet's theorem on infinitely many primes in arithmetic progression