# How to show that gcd of two quasiperiods is a quasiperiod?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem, dirichlet-character

Definition 3.1.1 in page 25 of [this book](https://users.renyi.hu/%7Emagap/classes/ceu/19_fall_analytic_number_theory/classical_analytic_number_theory.pdf) is the definition of quasiperod and Proposition 3.1.3. shows that gcd of two quasiperiods is a quasiperiod. The whole proof is clear except for the part about CRT.

I would appreciate a simple explanation of the following claim from the proof of Proposition 3.1.3:

Now choose an integer $w_1$ such that it is from the prescribed residue class modulo $d_2/ \gcd(d_1, d_2)$, and that for any prime divisor $p$ of $q$ not dividing $d_1d_2$, we have $w_1 \not\equiv −m/d_1\pmod p$. The existence of such integers is guaranteed by the Chinese Remainder Theorem. How holds $w_1 \not\equiv −m/d_1\pmod p$ and how it comes from CRT?

PS this is an exercise in Apostol's book Ch8 and also Montgomery's book Ch9. In Apostol "quasiperiod" is named "induced modulus".

Comment: In internet I found \notequiv for not congruent to, but it didn't work in the OP. Does someone knows the correct latex for that? Thanks

Comment: \not\equiv (in general \not will negate all relation symbols, usually in a visually good way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\forall i\!:\, w\not\equiv b\pmod{\!p_i}\!\iff\! \forall i\!:\, p_i\nmid w\!-\!b\!$ $\iff\! \forall i\!:\, (p_i,w\!-\!b)\!=\!1\!\iff\! \overbrace{\color{#0a0}{(P,w\!-\!b)\!=\!1}}^{\!\!\!\large P\ =\, \prod p_i}$

When $\,w\equiv a\pmod{\!d}\,$ so $\,w=a\!+\!nd,\,$ the above becomes $\,\color{#0a0}{(P,\,a\!-\!b+ n\,d)\!=\!1}.\,$ In OP we have  $(P,d)\!=\!1,\,$ so it is solvable for $\,n\,$ by the [Coprime Dirichlet Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/647665/242) (which - as shown there - is indeed provable by CRT, but also has a much simpler direct proof).

Comment: Thanks, I am reading your answer, for the first line p_i divides q and does not divide d_1d_2 and maybe gcd of these two not be 1

Comment: Second comment: in OP (q,d_i) may not be 1

Comment: So by  "any prime divisor $p$ of $q$ not dividing $d_1d_2$" you mean $q\nmid d_1d_2,\,$ not $\,p\nmid d_1d_2?\ $ Please quote the textbook *exactly* as written, and you should include more of the proof for context - one should not need to follow the link - which I did not.

Comment: No, the text means for any prime $p$ such that $p \mid q $ and $p \nmid d_1d_2$, am I right? Could you have a look at the text page 29, please? Following lines of text suggest that as well...

Comment: It is obvious from the OP. The rest of text is irrelevant that's why I didn't quote.

Comment: @Ali By definition every $\,p_i\,$ is coprime to $\,d_1d_2$ so coprime to $\,d_2,\,$ so their product $\,q\,$ is coprime to $\,d_2$ so also to its divisor $\,d = d_2/(d_1,d_2),\,$ i.e. $\,(q,d)=1.\ \ $

Comment: There are two types of prime divisors of $q$. those $p_i$ coprime to $d_1d_2$ and those divide $d_1d_2$. The product of this two sets divide $q$ and may not be coprime to $d_1d_2$ if $\gcd(q,d_1d_2)>1$. In OP, I have quoted from the text for those $p_i|q$ that $p_i$ coprime to $d_1d_2$ and product of them is not $q$

Comment: @Ali But the text requires that the incongruence $\,w\not\equiv b\,$ needs to hold only for those $p$ coprime to $d_1d_2\ \ $

Comment: So you have renamed q, ok let me think

Comment: @Ali There was a notation clash, I renamed my $\,q\,$ to $\,P = \prod p_i\ \ $

Comment: @Ali If $\,m/d_1\not\in\Bbb Z\,$ then we can use CRT to find an integer $\,b\equiv m/d_1\pmod{\!p_i}\,$ for all $\,i.\,$   The issues above were caused by the omission of necessary context for the proof.

Comment: No not relevant to CRT, since $d_1$ and $p_i$ are coprime so $w_1d_1=m$ has unique solution for $w_1$, namely $b$ - that's why I dropped my comment!

Comment: @Ali My prior comment (replying to your deleted comment), *is* relevant to the above proof - where $b$ is an integer (vs $\,b_i := md_1^{-1}\pmod{\!p_1}\,$ where the inverse depends on the modulus $p_i).\ $

Comment: I totally got it **except for one thing**: $(P,d)=1$ so $(P, t, d)=1$ for any $t$. So (by the link you provided) there is some $n$ such that $(P,a−b+nd)=1$ for any choice of $a$. So any $a$ or equivalently any $w$ works, **a contradiction?**

Comment: @Ali, Yes, glad all is clear now.

Comment: No there is a contradiction : how any choice of w mod d is OK?

Comment: ( i didn't downvote)

Comment: @Ali Why do you think it is contradictory that any $\,a\,$ works for the cited excerpt in your question?   (Don't worry abut the downvote  - it is likely due to site politics not math).

Comment: So we can choose any of $0,1,2,...,d-1$ for $w \equiv a$ mod $d$?! So any integer actually and one of them is congruent to $-m/d_1$ mod $p_i$, that is a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, in the notation of the linked proof, if $\,(a,c)=1$ then for *any* $\,b\,$ we have that  $\,(ax+b,c)=1$ is solvable for $\,x,\,$ i.e. if an A.P. has step-size $\,a\,$ coprime to $\,c\,$ then it has a term coprime  $\,c.\ \ $

Comment: Any $a$ means any $w_1$ and that means even $w_1 \equiv -m/d_1$ mod $p_i$ but this contradicts the assumption in OP

Comment: @Ali That the system of (in)congruences has a solution $\,w_a\,$ for any $\,a\,$ does not imply that you can further choose that solution to satisfy an arbitrary additional congruence too. Indeed by construction $\,w_a\not\equiv b\pmod{\!p}\,$ so there is no solution additionally satisfying $\,w_a\equiv b\pmod{\!p}\ \ $

Comment: Thanks a lot :) {a question not relevant to OP: I have just started my PhD in Riemann zeta function and I couldn't solve this very question by myself. Should I quit? Am I too dumb for advanced maths?}

Comment: @Ali This form of CRT is not well-covered in many elementary textbooks, so it often proves a stumbling block for students. So there is no need to be discouraged by that alone.